# What do I have to do in order to print Blob data types (PDF) retrieved from a webserver in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron, blob

I don't understand how to handle Blob-Files. I have an Electron application where I retrieve a pdf from a webserver. I want to silently print the pdf retrieved from the webserver using the printer name stored in `printer`. I tried different solutions including different node modules but it does not work and I am not quite getting what to do.
I would appreciate your help!

```
axios.get("getPdf", {responseType: "blob",headers: {'Accept': 'application/pdf'}).then(res => {
    let printer = printer_settings["printFormatX"];
    // I am not quite sure what to do now
    // I used different modules like 'pdf-to-printer' but it is not working like expected
    // I am generally unsure what to do with the retrieved pdf in order to print it
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:
I create a temporary file, then write the response data to it in order to then print it with the module `pdf-to-printer`

```
axios.get("getPdf", {responseType: "arraybuffer",headers: {'Accept': 'application/pdf'}).then(res => {
    let printer = printer_settings["printFormatX"];
    let tmpFile = __dirname + "/tmp_pdf.pdf"
    fs.writeFileSync(tmpFile, res.data, {encoding: "binary"});
    print(tmpFile, res.data, {printer: printer});
})
```